# How to return one of two unique value and avoid "Control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I understand the value of returning a value after all if/for/while methods have been run through like this:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        int rowHeight = 0;
        if (tableView == secondTable) {
            rowHeight = 62;
        }
        if (tableView == thirdTable) {
            rowHeight = 72;
        }
        return rowHeight;
    }
```

But what kind of variable could I declare that would be able to host different results... in this case, two different custom classes of UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // some variable here?

    if (tableView == secondTable) {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        CustomCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        return cell;                //don't return yet
    }
    if (tableView == thirdTable) {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        CustomCell3 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        return cell;                //don't return yet
    }

    // Ideally would return a UITableViewCell here to avoid "control may reach end of non-void function"
}
```

Comment: Since both of your cells are subclasses of UiTabkeViewCell you can just declare a UITableViewCell variable and then assign `cell` to this where you have your return statements and then return this variable at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not guaranteed that `tableView` will always be `secondTable` or `thirdTable` so it is best to return an empty cell in the other cases. It is better to have a empty cell than a crash from returning nothing.

It should look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (tableView == secondTable) {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[CustomCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

    } else if (tableView == thirdTable) {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[CustomCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

    } else {
        // init an empty cell of some kind
        // cell = ...
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Using this method uses downcasting from a custom class to the super class UITableViewCell.

Note that you have to cast explicitly to avoid compile-time warnings.

If you have intention to add more custom cells replace the if statement with a switch.

Comment: I personally prefer this approach where you only have one return and it is at the end of the function. 
I usually initialise the original variable to nil though, so if I miss something there is a consistent failure mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you only have the two table views, replace the second `if` with an `else`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == secondTable) {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        CustomCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        return cell;
    } else {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        CustomCell3 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

In general, avoid multiple `if` statements if only one can ever be true. Use `if/else if/else` as needed.

```
if (condA) {
} else if (condB) {
} else {
}
```

Another option would be to use something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *result = nil;

    if (tableView == secondTable) {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        CustomCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        result = cell;
    } else {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        CustomCell3 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        result = cell;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But this has no benefit over the previous suggestion other than there being a single `return` at the end of the method.

Comment: I'll add that to help understanding in the future, you may do this: `if (condA){}else/*condB*/{}` Put in comment the other case. That's what I do when I do an if/elseif/elseif/else with 2 booleans for instance (if(A&&B)elseif(!A&&B)elseif(A&&!B)else/*!A&&!B*/